# How to add separator line for each row in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipickerview, ios9.3

I am using swift with xcode7.3.1.I would like to add separator lines for each row in UIPickerView.I would like to implement UIPickerview as the following screenshot

[image]

How to solve this issue.Please help me

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view` method, instead of using `titleForRow ..`method
2. Here create your custom view, with label and bottomline(UIView- as line) and return that view.

you will have required effect by this step.